# Двойной запуск Qt приложения

Tags: qt5, qtcreator, qt, c++

Здравствуйте, у меня возникает следующая проблема:

Во время запуска происходит сборка и **до ее окончания** приложение со сплешскрином запускается в свернутом виде, его даже развернуть можно и увидеть, которое ест около 200 000 КБ памяти. Потом, **когда сборка заканчивается**, эта свернутая копия закрывается со сплешскрином и открывается нормальная версия, которая ест около 3 000 КБ.

Моя последовательность действий

1. я создаю Qt Project (Qt 5, MinGW) с шаблоном mainWindow.cpp, mainWindow.h, mainWindow.ui
2. запускаю, собираю, окошко открывается и приложение ест 3 000 КБ памяти по диспетчеру задач, все как надо
3. меняю main.cpp приведенный ниже, остальные файлы как есть
4. собираю
5. запускаю
6. во время запуска возникает проблема

Как избавится от нее избавится?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>
void loadModules(QSplashScreen* psplash)
{
    QTime time;
    time.start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ) {
        if (time.elapsed() > 40) {
            time.start();
            ++i;
        }
        psplash->showMessage("Loading: "
                             + QString::number(i) + "%",
                             Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignBottom,
                             Qt::white
                            );
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    QSplashScreen splash(QPixmap(".././images/splashScreen.bmp"));
    splash.show();
    loadModules(&splash);
    splash.finish(&w);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

**.pro - файл**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MountainGoat_OCR
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

[параметры сборки:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVrtd.png)

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Картинка bmp видимо мегабайт 100. Если сильно хочется картинку - грузите png, хотя оно в памяти все равно распакуется.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так.

```
    //QSplashScreen splash(QPixmap(".././images/splashScreen.bmp"));
    //splash.show();
    //loadModules(&splash);
    //splash.finish(&w);
```

Можно попробовать.

**Обновление**

Скорее всего проблема в том, что окно не успевает инициализироваться. Наверное другая машина побыстрее вашей будет. Можно попробовать перенести отображение сплеша в другой поток и из него вызывать только обновление картинки\либо конец отображения сплэша и вызов отображения окна. Может быть loadModules занимает слишком много времени и интерфейс не успевает отрисоваться.

Comment: Дело в том, что splashScreen мне нужен. К тому же на другой машине проект запустился как надо.
Картинка весит меньше мегабайте

Comment: @Deadkenny запустил в другом потоке и убрал loadModules, так как это просто для задержки отображения было. Очистил папку и проект, проблема все-равно воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вставить qApp->processEvents() после splash.show() и после обновления сообщения, может быть поможет.

**Update**

В документации приведены вот такие снипеты:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QPixmap pixmap(":/splash.png");
    QSplashScreen splash(pixmap);
    splash.show();
    app.processEvents();
    ...
    QMainWindow window;
    window.show();
    splash.finish(&window);
    return app.exec();
}
```

> Since the splash screen is typically
> displayed before the event loop has
> started running, it is necessary to
> periodically call
> QApplication::processEvents() to
> receive the mouse clicks.

```
QPixmap pixmap(":/splash.png");
QSplashScreen *splash = new QSplashScreen(pixmap);
splash->show();

... // Loading some items
splash->showMessage("Loaded modules");

qApp->processEvents();

... // Establishing connections
splash->showMessage("Established connections");

qApp->processEvents();
```

На примере периодически вызывется qApp->processEvents(), чтобы в eventloop ничего не накапливалось и события выполнялись своевременно, т.к. eventloop еще не запущен. Я думаю Deadkenny прав и окно не успевает отрисовываться по каким-то причинам. Поэтому в loadModules или перед его вызовом попробуй вызвать qApp->processEvents(), потому что во время выполнения loadModules у runtime нет возможности выполнять события из eventloop(например, не успевшие выполниться события отрисовки).

Еще цитата из документации:

```
void QSplashScreen::showMessage(const QString & message, int alignment = Qt::AlignLeft, const QColor & color = Qt::black) [slot]
Draws the message text onto the splash screen with color color and aligns the text according to the flags in alignment.

To make sure the splash screen is repainted immediately, you can call QCoreApplication's processEvents() after the call to showMessage(). You usually want this to make sure that the message is kept up to date with what your application is doing (e.g., loading files).
```